# How to connect secondary distribution panels in series? 3 Phase Germany

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Mine is a 3-phase German household.  Main panel serves the kitchen and a 5 conductor 10 mm^2 with each phase fused 16A (w/ Hager FS) to the secondary panel upstairs.  This services 6 rooms, a bath, and attic w/ 10A FS and a 3 phase CDA440D FI (RCD).

How should I make the connection at this secondary panel to another secondary panel servicing the garage?  Specifically, what is the right device or connector to bridge two service lines?  The panel is a Hager Volta 1P30 3-row, 36 unit.  The 5 conductor 10 mm2 input from main panel must feed the 5 conductor 6 mm2 output to the next secondary panel.

The ground/PE/green-yellow should just share the PE bus.

I assume each RCD servicing the upstairs rooms should have its own neutral/null/blue bus.  Thus, I need a separate neutral connector.

The 3 phases (L1,L2,L3) could be connected via switch (Hager SH363N), or Hager KC325?  Or is another series fuse better (Hager MBN316A)?

Comment: Do you intend to have the garage panel to be secondary to the not-kitchen panel, or the two panels to be effectively side-by-side?

Comment: Are you sure your first subpanel is fused 16A?  10mm2 and 6mm2 wire are both wildly oversized for 16A.  Oversizing wires is a good thing though.  If you are willing to size the overcurrent protection in the main panel to a value allowed for 6mm2 wire, I see no need for overcurrent protection in subpanel #1 for the run to sub #2.  We yanks call that a "through lug".

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Garage panel will be secondary to the not-kitchen panel, i.e. in series.  Main -> secondary -> garage.

Comment: @Harper I am very sure the first subpanel is fused 16A.  The "electrician*", insisted on 10 mm^2 to the secondary and 6 mm^2 to the garage.  I had originally 5x2.5mm^2 to the garage, which he made me replace with the 6 mm^2.
* I fired my electrician for connecting 240VAC to the outside temperature sensor of my furnace, destroying the control module.  Inexcusable incompetence.  Plus his work was sloppy.

Comment: A stopped clock (12 hour analog) is right twice a day.  We want electricians to be right a lot more often than that, but  large wires there was a good call